# Add multitouch to SDL 1.2.15

Tags: sdl, x11, multi-touch

I have an application based on SDL 1.2.15 and I would like to include multitouch feature. So I am trying to include, as SDL2 does, by `XISelectEvents` doing something like this:

```
/* Set up MPX events */
XIEventMask eventmask;

eventmask.deviceid = XIAllMasterDevices;
eventmask.mask_len = XIMaskLen(XI_LASTEVENT);
eventmask.mask = (unsigned char*) calloc(eventmask.mask_len, sizeof(char));

/* Events we want to listen for */
XISetMask(eventmask.mask, XI_TouchBegin);
XISetMask(eventmask.mask, XI_TouchUpdate);
XISetMask(eventmask.mask, XI_TouchEnd);


/* Register events on the window */
XISelectEvents(display, win, &eventmask, 1);
```

This code is working properly on a simple X11 application and I am getting X11 events for multitouch `GenericEvent`.

So this encouraged me to include at the end of `static int X11_CreateWindow` function on SDL_x11video.c the next code:

```
XIEventMask eventmask;

eventmask.deviceid = XIAllMasterDevices;
eventmask.mask_len = XIMaskLen(XI_LASTEVENT);
eventmask.mask = (unsigned char*) calloc(eventmask.mask_len, sizeof(char));

// Events we want to listen for
XISetMask(eventmask.mask, XI_TouchBegin);
XISetMask(eventmask.mask, XI_TouchUpdate);
XISetMask(eventmask.mask, XI_TouchEnd);

printf( "Goto register on XISelectEvents\n");
printf("XISelectEvents: %d, %d\n", __LINE__, SDL_Display);
// Register events on the window
if (XISelectEvents(SDL_Display, SDL_Window, &eventmask, 1) != Success)
{
  printf( "Impossible to run  XISelectEvents\n");
}
printf( "register on XISelectEvents DONE\n");
```

The point is, although XISelectEvents looks like working properly, I am getting when using my touch pencil X11 events related with mouse (`ButtonPress`, `ButtonRelease`, `MotionNotify`) instead of `GenericEvent` expected.

As limitation, I cannot change to SDL2, migrate task could be huge.

Any suggestion?